# The array is getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xsd

I have a nested loop. in the inner most loop I am creating the array and when the control comes out of the inner loop, then I am coppying the entire array formed in the inner loop to the new array.

The problem is that the values are getting over written in the end.
The data I have will go for 2 outer loop and each loop will have 5 and 24 inner loops respectively.

But in the end the total data I get is the data from the last loop.

Here is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "Sample.xsd",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        var xmlObj  = $.parseXML(data);

        var buff = $(xmlObj).find("xs\\:complexType");

        var xmlObj1 = [];           var buff1 = [];
        var j = 0;
        $(buff).each(function(i){

            buff1.splice(0, buff1.length);
            $this = $(this);

            $this.find("xs\\:element").each(function(index){
                buff1[index] = $(this).attr('name');
            });
            xmlObj1[j] = buff1;
            console.log(xmlObj1);
            j++;
        });


        console.log(xmlObj1);
    },
    error: function(err){

    }
});
});
```

If you want I can attach the xsd file as well. But I dnt think its important.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I think you are overdoing it. The following should give you the expected result:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Sample.xsd",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            var xmlObj = $.parseXML(data), xmlObj1 = new Array(),
                buff = $(xmlObj).find("xs\\:complexType");

            $(buff).each(function(i) {
                var buff1 = new Array();
                $(this).find("xs\\:element").each(function(ii) {
                    buff1[ii] = $(this).attr('name');
                });
                xmlObj1[i] = buff1;
            });

            console.log(xmlObj1);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/EKHVC/) based on similar idea.

Comment: Actually you are right. When I made the buff1 array as the local one, it worked like charm. But what is the problem when its not local to the loop? What exactly happes that results in overwriting of the array?

Comment: Your splice method was your problem. Splice is best used for manipulating an array after it's built, but in your scenario, you're still building the array, thus splice doesn't quite fit. I haven't tested it thoroughly to back my claim, that's simply my first guess. When I saw what you were doing (building a multidimensional array) I thought, "I do this everyday! There's no need for all that splicing and pushing!" Thus I just simply rewrote your code the way I would have written it to start with.

Comment: Wow, but I was getting the same error without that splice method :)

Comment: Yeah, i checked, the issue is with where `buff` is "reset", thus why i declare it "within" the for loop. This way it is reset everytime. The indexing is made easy thanks to jQuery. No need to maintain that `j` variable when `.each` already has it's own indexing. I just simply keep up with parent child index by adding another `i` for each `.each` declared within another. Anyway, sometimes I overthink things and it always comes back to simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reassign it as empty to the array value after it is assigned before it starts a new loop.

Comment: I am sorry, but i didnt get you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `buff1` as a local variable to the `$(buff).each` loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "Sample.xsd",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            var xmlObj  = $.parseXML(data), xmlObj1 = [];
            var buff = $(xmlObj).find("xs\\:complexType");
            $(buff).each(function(i){
                var buff1 = [], $this = $(this);
                $this.find("xs\\:element").each(function(index){
                    buff1.push($(this).attr('name'));
                });
                xmlObj1.push(buff1)
            });

            console.log(xmlObj1);
        },
        error: function(err){

        }
    });
});
```